# Calculus - finding the difficult limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-(\cos x)^{\sin x}}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm struggling with the following limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-(\cos x)^{\sin x}}{x^2}$$

Don't know where to start with this. Hints/solutions very appreciated.

Comment: l'Hopital twice.

Comment: Thx. It works! Wonder, whether there is another method of finding this limit without using l'Hopital.

Comment: I thought of series expansion, but algebra is nasty then... Any help very appreciated.

Comment: Series would be a good idea. Start with $\sin(x)\log(cos(x))$

Comment: $\frac{1-(\cos x)^{\sin x}}{x^2}=\frac{x}{2}+o(x^3)$

Answer (score 6):

For a series approach, just look at $y(x) = \cos(x)^{\sin(x)}$ and consider the logarithm $\ln y = \sin(x) \ln \cos(x)$. For $x \to 0$ then $\ln y \approx (x + x^3/3) \ln (1 - x^2/2)$ and the expansion for the $\ln$ term is well known.

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - (\cos x)^{\sin x}}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \exp(\sin x\log \cos x)}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= -\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\exp(\sin x\log \cos x) - 1}{\sin x\log \cos x}\cdot\frac{\sin x\log \cos x}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= -\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log\cos x}{x}\notag\\
&= -\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log\cos^{2} x}{2x}\notag\\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 - \sin^{2} x)}{\sin^{2}x}\cdot\frac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}\cdot x\notag\\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\cdot(-1)\cdot 1\cdot 0\notag\\
&= 0\notag
\end{align}
Like most of the limit problems seen on MSE, this one is also evaluated using standard limits without the use of advanced tools like L'Hospital's Rule or Taylor's series.